# Ruby - Evaluate escaped interpolated sections in a string

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I feel like this should be obvious but I'm having a mental block.  Using Ruby, let's say that I have a string which might or might not contain some escaped string-interpolation segments, like this:

```
s1 = "Hello world"
=> "Hello world"
s2 = "Hello \#{foo}, hello \#{bar}"
=> "Hello \#{foo}, hello \#{bar}"
#note that the string-interpolation (#{}) segments above are escaped, so they're not interpolated 
#- that is, it doesn't try to look up what foo and bar are, it's just a dumb string.
```

I want to "render out" these strings effectively, like so:

```
foo = "chunky"
=> "chunky"
bar = "bacon"
=> "bacon"
myfunc(s1)
=> "Hello world"
myfunc(s2)
=> "Hello chunky, hello bacon"
```

This seems like it should be fundamental but i just can't see it...

**EDIT** - i've found one way to do this which is to escape the quotes in the original string too, then it can be eval'd:  feels kind of clunky though.

```
>> s1 = "\"Hello world\""
=> "\"Hello world\""
>> s2 = "\"Hello \#{foo}, hello \#{bar}\""
=> "\"Hello \#{foo}, hello \#{bar}\""
>> foo = "chunky"
=> "chunky"
>> bar = "bacon"
=> "bacon"
>> eval s1
=> "Hello world"
>> eval s2
=> "Hello chunky, hello bacon"
```

It also requires normal strings to have their quotes escaped too which isn't ideal.

Comment: `eval "\"#{s2}\""` ?

Comment: yep, that works... it's not pretty but it works...

Comment: I'm trying to wrap this as an instance method of String, but it doesn't work because inside the method call it doesn't have access to local scope and so doesn't know what "foo" and "bar" are.

Answer (score 2):

You're "doing it wrong". There is a standard practice for this: Use [`sprintf`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf) instead of `eval`.

Rather than defining the string like this:

```
s2 = 'Hello #{foo}, hello #{bar}'
```

(Note: Using single quotation marks rather than double quotation marks is an easier/simpler way of defining the un-evaluated string.)

Instead, define it like this:

```
s2 = 'Hello %{foo}, hello %{bar}'
```

And then to *interpolate* the parameters, use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(s2, { foo: "Chunky", bar: "Bacon"})
```

Or equivalently:

```
s2 % { foo: "Chunky", bar: "Bacon"}
```

Comment: ah thanks - is there a way to make it automatically use local variables rather than explicitly passing them through?

Comment: To be honest, that just sounds dangerous and ugly. At best it's a demonstration how to create security problems and confuse readers with unnecessary magic. But you could automatically construct a hash of all local variables via: `local_variables.map {|v| [v, eval(v.to_s)]}.to_h`.

Comment: **Or**, if you happen to be using a template engine (is this a rails view, by any chance??) then maybe you already have access to the local variables in a nice hash? For example, perhaps you could do: `s2 % local_assigns`

Answer (score 1):

if you take the simple answer:

```
eval "\"#{s2}\""
```

which encloses the `s2` string in double quotes and then runs it through `eval` to evaluate the string, we can then look to proceduralise it, to make further coding look prettier, and easier to debug:

defining the objects as a `def`, this has a draw-back that it only evaluates global variables, as you only pass the string into the procedure:

```
# this one depends on global variables ...
def myfunc(x)
  eval "\"#{x}\""
end

myfunc(s2)
```

defining the object as a `lambda` ([Ruby Blacks and Lambdas](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/)), this has the advantage of running "in place", so local variables should be evaluated:

```
# should use local variables
expand= ->(x) { eval "\"#{x}\"" }

expand.(s2)
# or
expand[s2]
# or in long form:
expand.call(s2)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it